# TypeError only occurs while debugging

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger, mxgraph

While debugging an unrelated issue, my code crashed in a way it had not done prior to my opening the browser debugger.

`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

The error occurs in an event handler for moving an `mxCell`.

```
adjustPortPosition(sender, event)
{
  ...
  for(var i = 0; i < event.properties.cells.length; i++)
  {
    var node = event.properties.cells[i];
    var edges = this.graph.getEdges(node); // crashes here!
    ...
  }
}
```

The crash occurs after the call to `mxGraph.getEdges`. When I stepped into that call, everything in that method executed without problem, and the value it returned was an array of 3 `mxCell` objects, not `undefined` or `null`. `getEdges` does not appear in the stack trace, but the line on which it's called does. All I'm doing is assigning the return value to a variable, so even if it was `undefined` or `null` it shouldn't have to do any sort of conversion.

This only happens when moving a vertex that has child vertices. Any vertices in my graph without children do not produce an error.

To make the situation even less clear, the bug does not occur consistently. Without changing the code, it has switched multiple times between crashing every time I move the vertex while debugging and not being able to reproduce the crash at all.

Here's mxgraph.getEdges:

```
mxGraph.prototype.getEdges = function(cell, parent, incoming, outgoing, includeLoops, recurse)
{
    incoming = (incoming != null) ? incoming : true;
    outgoing = (outgoing != null) ? outgoing : true;
    includeLoops = (includeLoops != null) ? includeLoops : true;
    recurse = (recurse != null) ? recurse : false;

    var edges = [];
    var isCollapsed = this.isCellCollapsed(cell);
    var childCount = this.model.getChildCount(cell);

    for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        var child = this.model.getChildAt(cell, i);

        if (isCollapsed || !this.isCellVisible(child))
        {
            edges = edges.concat(this.model.getEdges(child, incoming, outgoing));
        }
    }

    edges = edges.concat(this.model.getEdges(cell, incoming, outgoing));
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++)
    {
        var state = this.view.getState(edges[i]);

        var source = (state != null) ? state.getVisibleTerminal(true) : this.view.getVisibleTerminal(edges[i], true);
        var target = (state != null) ? state.getVisibleTerminal(false) : this.view.getVisibleTerminal(edges[i], false);

        if ((includeLoops && source == target) || ((source != target) && ((incoming &&
            target == cell && (parent == null || this.isValidAncestor(source, parent, recurse))) ||
            (outgoing && source == cell && (parent == null ||
                    this.isValidAncestor(target, parent, recurse))))))
        {
            result.push(edges[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at NetView.adjustPortPosition (net-view.js:1805)
at mxGraph.mxEventSource.fireEvent (mxEventSource.js:185)
at mxGraph.moveCells (mxGraph.js:6009)
at mxGraphHandler.moveCells (mxGraphHandler.js:1016)
at mxGraphHandler.mouseUp (mxGraphHandler.js:907)
at mxGraph.fireMouseEvent (mxGraph.js:12612)
at mxCellRenderer.<anonymous> (mxCellRenderer.js:851)
at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (mxUtils.js:208)`
```

Comment: Is this code executing inside of a callback?  Sounds like with the inconsistency (and only showing in debug mode), it could be some variation of a race condition.

Comment: It's in an event handler, but I don't know the details of how mxgraph is doing its events under the hood. The only other event handler I have running on that event doesn't do anything other than logging, so it shouldn't be making any changes to the graph.

Comment: This sounds really interesting, but we'll probably need more details. Can you maybe post the stack trace, and some more of the relevant code (e.g. `getEdges`)?

Comment: console.log output the array prior to coming into the loop, what does that show?

Comment: @David at the beginning of the loop, event.properties.cells contains a single mxCell with one child mxCell and 3 edges.

Comment: @MátéSafranka getEdges and the stack trace now included.